Loop over array cyclically
Is there any way to make cyclic loop over array without PadLeft,PadRight, ArrayPad?
So supposed operator DoC works like this:
arr = {1,2,3};
DoC[Print@e, {e, arr}, 10]

Output: 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1
(*At least 10 cyclically repeated elements of arr*)

UPD
Well, in a way it’s a learning question, for comparison of Mathematica' possibilities.
Thanks for the answers, I learned many useful features.
As to the substance looks like for big arrays the best method is with QuotientRemainder, and for small enough built-in padding is good.

n = 10;
Table[{a, b, c}[[Mod[n, 3, 1]]], {n, 1, n}]

@cvgmy Only problem is that integer mod is typically one of the slowest machine instructions available. =/

Sounds like an XY problem. Why not use padding?

What kind of operations $f$ you want to apply on the cyclic list? Suppose $f$ is very time-consuming but of parallelizable type (no side effects). Then apply $f$ first on arr only, and then make a cycle from the resulting answer list. The existing solution repeats the same computation many times.

You could use "Mod" to get the correct index and "Sow"/"Reap" to assemble the new list:
doc[list_, n_] := Module[{len = Length[list]},
  Reap[
    Do[Sow[list[[Mod[i, len, 1]]]], {i, n}]
    ][[2, 1]]
  ]

With this:
doc[{1, 2, 3}, 10]

{1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1}


This one uses a single QuotientRemainder and a loop unrolling instead of a Mod in each single iteration. It also does not create any copies of arr:
ClearAll[DoC];
DoC[f_, arr_, k_] := Module[{q, r},
   {q, r} = QuotientRemainder[k, Length[arr]];
   Do[Scan[f, arr], q];
   Do[f[arr[[i]]], {i, 1, r}];
   ];


Using Table and Take:
DoC[list_, n_] := Take[Flatten@Table[list, {Ceiling[n/Length[list]]}], n]

list = {1, 2, 3};

DoC[list, 10]


{1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1}


One way could be:
arr = {1, 2, 3};
min = 10;
DoC[k_List, min_] := 
 NestWhile[Join[#1, #1] &, k, Length@# < min &] // Take[#, min] &

Table[DoC[arr, i], {i, 5, 15, 2}] // Grid




Well, but it looks like just version of ArrayPad

arr = Alphabet[][[;; 3]]

Update
Partition[arr, 10, 4, 1]

(* {{a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c, a}}

Partition[arr, #, 4, 1] & /@ Range[11]

(* {
    {{a}},
    {{a,b}},
    {{a,b,c}},
    {{a,b,c,a}},
    {{a,b,c,a,b}},
    {{a,b,c,a,b,c}},
    {{a,b,c,a,b,c,a}},
    {{a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b}},
    {{a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c}},
    {{a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c,a}},
    {{a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b}}
   } *)


A 'point-free' version:
(CurryApplied[4 -> {1, 4, 3, 2}][Partition][arr, 1, 4] /@ Range[11])

(* {{{a}},{{a,b}},{{a,b,c}},{{a,b,c,a}},{{a,b,c,a,b}},   
   {{a,b,c,a,b,c}},{{a,b,c,a,b,c,a}},{{a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b}},
   {{a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c}},{{a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c,a}},
   {{a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b}}} *)

Original Answer
SubstitutionSystem[MapApply[Rule]@Partition[arr, 2, 1, 1], First@arr, 9] 
  // Flatten

(* {a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c, a} *)


A version using RotateLeft:
DoC[arr_, n_] := NestList[RotateLeft, arr, n - 1][[;; , 1]]


Yes, it's interesting compromise between padding and Mod !
